# Eclipse plugin - SWT_AWT not working on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, swt-awt

I'm developing an [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/) plugin using the [SWT_AWT](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/awt/SWT_AWT.html) bridge in order to design the gui using Swing.
It works perfectly on Windows but when I try to run it in OSX i get this error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented    
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: apple.awt.CEmbeddedFrame
```

I found this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374199) but I still don't understand how to fix this...
Any idea?

**Edit**: I'm on Mac OSX 10.7.5, my Java version is 7u21, Eclipse is Juno sr2

Comment: On witch version of Mac OS are you?

Comment: This should be the fix... but I don't know how to integrate it in my Eclipse:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/commit/?id=269e9bd88659168cd99ab994fb73a4e91595fd06

Comment: Did you tried with Indigo? I've never have this kind of problem with it

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I'm gonna try

Comment: Tell me if it fixed your problem ;)

Comment: Nothing... exact same problem with Indigo :(

Comment: Well I don't know how to apply a patch Lorenzo, but you can go manually by replacing the red lines with the green ones...

Comment: manually change eclipse code...? it doesn't sound possible :D

Comment: In fact, you just have to change this file : Eclipse SWT AWT/cocoa/org/eclipse/swt/awt/SWT_AWT.java witch my be possible :)

Comment: Solved in another way :) thank you VBB anyway

Comment: That's the principal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by updating Java to [7u40](https://jdk7.java.net/download.html) (maybe it wasn't necessary) and by adding this line of code:

```
SWT_AWT.embeddedFrameClass = "sun.lwawt.macosx.CViewEmbeddedFrame";
```